# Image Archives for <hr> and border image replacement

Tags: html, images

Do you know any quality image archives for **<\hr>** and **border**

For example an image archives for <\hr> : http://siahdesign.com/archives/210

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This article](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/09/09/the-hr-contest-results-download-your-fresh-hr-line-now/) on Smashing Magazine has some good horizontal rule image replacements.